# Vaadin 8 alpha/beta prerelease fail with “Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find” errors

Tags: java, maven, vaadin, project, vaadin8

I have not been able to try the alpha and beta versions of Vaadin 8.

➥ What exactly do I need to do to change a working *Vaadin 8.5.2* project to use *Vaadin 8.6.0beta1*?

## Scenario

I am using IntelliJ 2018.3, configured to use external Maven 3.5.4.

I followed the instructions seen at:
https://vaadin.com/framework/releases/8.6.0.beta1

Actually, my POM already had the pair of `<id>vaadin-prereleases</id>` entries as shown on that page:

```xml
<repositories>
         <!-- ... -->

         <repository>
             <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
             <name>Vaadin Pre-releases</name>
             <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
         </repository>

</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
         <!-- ... -->

         <pluginRepository>
             <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
             <name>Vaadin Pre-releases</name>
             <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
         </pluginRepository>

</pluginRepositories>
```

## Problem

When I change:

```xml
<vaadin.version>8.5.2</vaadin.version>
<vaadin.plugin.version>8.5.2</vaadin.plugin.version>
```

to:

```xml
<vaadin.version>8.6.0beta1</vaadin.version>
<vaadin.plugin.version>8.6.0beta1</vaadin.plugin.version>
```

…I get the following errors when running a Maven `clean`, basically about `Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:pom:8.6.0beta1`

Console:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:pom:8.6.0beta1 in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 41, column 25
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar is missing. @ line 58, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.vaadin:vaadin-push:jar is missing. @ line 62, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:jar is missing. @ line 66, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:jar is missing. @ line 70, column 21
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.basilbourque.example:grid-refresh:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/basilbourque/IdeaProjects/GridRefresh/pom.xml) has 5 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:pom:8.6.0beta1 in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 41, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.vaadin:vaadin-server:jar is missing. @ line 58, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.vaadin:vaadin-push:jar is missing. @ line 62, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiled:jar is missing. @ line 66, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.vaadin:vaadin-themes:jar is missing. @ line 70, column 21
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

I do not have these problems when changing those two lines to an official release such as `8.5.0` or `8.5.1`. The problem is only with the alpha and beta prereleases.

Here is one example POM file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.basilbourque.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>grid-refresh</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>grid-refresh</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <!-- Changing this… -->
        <!--<vaadin.version>8.5.2</vaadin.version>-->
        <!--<vaadin.plugin.version>8.5.2</vaadin.plugin.version>-->
        <!-- …to this… -->
        <vaadin.version>8.6.0beta1</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>8.6.0beta1</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <!-- …fails with an error message:  Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:pom:8.6.0beta1 in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of vaadin-addons has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 41, column 25 -->
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.4.12.v20180830</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>10</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>10</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- If there are no local customizations, this can also be "fetch" or "cdn" -->
        <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/styles.css</include>
                                <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
                running jetty:run on the command line. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
            <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <name>Vaadin Pre-releases</name>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <name>Vaadin Pre-releases</name>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

I tried deleting the `.m2` > `repository` folder in my home folder. Did not help.

Comment: You seem to have snapshot configured as well, try to change  that to:               <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. There is a `.` missing in the version string. It should be `8.6.0.beta1` instead of `8.6.0beta1`.
2. The prerelease repository is only configured for the `vaadin-prerelease` profile, which isn't enabled by default. You need to change your `pom.xml` to always enable the profile or manually enable it when building the application (using e.g. `-Pvaadin-prerelease` from the command line). The profile is not enabled by default for performance reasons.

See this screenshot from [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2018, showing:

- The `vaadin-prerelease` profile enabled by a checkbox.
- Valid value in `vaadin-version` element of POM file.

[image: screenshot of IntelliJ 2018 showing POM file in editor along with "vaadin-prelease" selected in "Maven" panel]