# Change Maven-driven project based on Vaadin 11 to Vaadin 12 alpha version?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, vaadin, project, vaadin-flow

## Problem

I have a working project in [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 2018.3 for [Vaadin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin) 11, created using the [*Project Base*](https://vaadin.com/start/latest/project-base) starter-pack.

➥ How do I switch from *Vaadin 11.0.0* to *Vaadin 12.0.0.alpha4* ?

My Question here is similar to this one, [*Vaadin 8 alpha/beta prerelease fail with “Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find” errors*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52583609/642706). [The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52585857/642706) on that page was to enable a `vaadin-prerelease` checkbox in the *Profiles* list in the *Maven* sidebar of IntelliJ. But with a Vaadin 11 project, the only such checkbox found there is labeled `production-mode`.

## Failed Solution

In the project’s Maven POM file, `pom.xml`, I tried switching:

```xml
<vaadin.version>11.0.0</vaadin.version>
```

…to:

```xml
<vaadin.version>12.0.0.alpha4</vaadin.version>
```

…having taken that version number string from the [currently published JavaDoc site](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/12.0.0.alpha4/overview-summary.html).

When executing a Maven `clean` with this version number in place, I get these errors:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:pom:12.0.0.alpha4 in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Vaadin Directory has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 28, column 25
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.vaadin:vaadin-core:jar is missing. @ line 39, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar is missing. @ line 46, column 21
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project com.basilbourque.acme:acme:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/basilbourque/IdeaProjects/Acme/pom.xml) has 3 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:pom:12.0.0.alpha4 in http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of Vaadin Directory has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 28, column 25 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for com.vaadin:vaadin-core:jar is missing. @ line 39, column 21
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:jar is missing. @ line 46, column 21
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Comment: For Vaadin 14, see: [*Configure Maven pom to access Vaadin 14 alpha pre-release*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57910701/642706). [My solution there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913824/642706) is much the same as [my solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53028667/642706).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The easy way

Vaadin Ltd now makes this easier. They added a tab on the page listing starter-packs for a POM pre-configured to use the latest pre-release.

https://vaadin.com/start/pre-release

[image: screenshot of web page for downloading starter-packs that now includes a tab for “Pre Release” version]

## The manual way

I do *not* know if the following solution is proper, but it seems to be working. Unfortunately a solution is not documented on the Vaadin site, so [I put in a request](https://github.com/vaadin/platform/issues/391).

## Configure *prerelease* Maven repositories

It seems the [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) file built by the *Project Base* starter-pack lacks the necessary [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) configuration settings to find the alpha/beta pre-release versions of Vaadin.

As of 2018-11-15, for Vaadin 12.0.0.beta2, take a working project such as one created from "Project Base" on the Vaadin pago of starter-packs, and make the following changes. This works today, but I have had [much trouble over past weeks](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17210310/update-a-vaadin-10-project-to-vaadin-11-beta). I suspect the problem was that some Maven or Vaadin repositories were not updated properly, and were missing some key file(s). At any rate, it works today.

First, find the latest alpha or beta version number at the [*Releases*](https://github.com/vaadin/platform/releases) page for *vaadin/platform* on GitHub. Today that is `12.0.0.beta2`.

(1)

Refresh your local cache for Maven.

In IntelliJ 2018, choose `Preferences`/`Settings` > `Build, Execution, Deployment` > `Build Tools` > `Maven` > `Repositories` > `Update` (button).

[image]

(2)

In the POM file of your project, change this:

```
<vaadin.version>11.0.2</vaadin.version>
```

… to this:

```
 <vaadin.version>12.0.0.beta2</vaadin.version>
```

(3)

**Inside** the `repositories` element, add this:

```
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
    </repository>
```

(4)

**Below** the `repositories` element, add this:

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <!-- Repository needed for prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

(5)

Perform a Maven `clean` and `install`.

Verify that your [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) reports no errors.

---

Here is a complete working [POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model) that I adapted from the [*Project Base*](https://vaadin.com/start/latest/project-base) found on the [page of starter-packs](https://vaadin.com/start/latest).

To find my 3 changes, search for the phrasing: `alphas-betas`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.basilbourque.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>acme</artifactId>
    <name>Acme</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <!--<vaadin.version>11.0.2</vaadin.version>-->
        <!--Change above line to line below for alphas-betas-->
        <vaadin.version>12.0.0.beta2</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>

        <!--Add this for alphas-betas-->
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <!--Add this for alphas-betas-->
    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- Repository needed for prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added to provide logging output as Flow uses -->
        <!-- the unbound SLF4J no-operation (NOP) logger implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Jetty plugin for easy testing without a server -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.4.11.v20180605</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>1</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode can be activated with either property or profile -->
            <id>production-mode</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>vaadin.productionMode</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-production-files</goal>
                                    <goal>package-for-production</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. Alphas and betas are published to the prereleases maven repository, and not maven central.

Comment: @JensJansson Do you know why the `vaadin-prerelease` checkbox in Maven “Profiles” pane in version 8 but not in Flow?

Comment: I’m not sure about it. I Use maven more from command line, so I’m not familiar with that panel in IntelliJ. The extra repository is most likely somehow configured differently in your pom.xml. Alternatively the the Vaadin 8 Mavennplugin has an extra profile configured, which isn’t present in the Vaadin platform.