# Configure Maven pom to access Vaadin 14 alpha/beta pre-release

Tags: maven, vaadin, pom.xml, release

I see on the [documentation page](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.4/overview-summary.html) for [Vaadin Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow) that while version `14.0.4` is current, there a version `14.0.0alpha1`.

Merely updating this element in my [Maven POM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven#Project_Object_Model):

```xml
<vaadin.version>14.1.0alpha1</vaadin.version>
```

…is not enough, as this pre-release is not yet available in the usual Maven repositories. As I vaguely recall from past experience, I need to configure my POM to access a special Maven repository for Vaadin pre-release versions. But cannot recall the details, and I am no Maven maven.

Comment: On a related note: [*Create a new Vaadin Flow 16/17 project using plain Java Servlets without Spring/CDI*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63496047/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [my own Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53028667/642706) to [my own Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53028557/642706) about an earlier version of Vaadin (1 & 12). The centerpiece of that Answer applies here.

Make these three edits to your Maven POM file.

## (1) Version

Change:

```xml
<vaadin.version>14.0.4</vaadin.version>
```

…to:

```xml
<vaadin.version>14.1.0.beta3</vaadin.version>
```

## (2) Add a `<repository>`

**Inside** the `<repositories>` tag, add this element:

```
    <!-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/57913824/642706 -->
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
    </repository>
```

## (3) Add `<pluginRepositories>`

**Between** the end of the `<repositories>` element and the beginning of the `<dependencyManagement>` element, paste:

```xml
<pluginRepositories>
    <!-- Repository needed for prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

## (4) Maven `clean`/`install`

Save your POM. Do a Maven `clean` and `install`. Wait. And wait. And wait some more for *many* downloads, hundreds, maybe more. Takes several minutes on a 70 Mbps internet connection.

Then you should be able to run your web app with the new alpha or beta version of Vaadin 14.

---

Here is an example POM that is currently working for me. May have some extra `<dependency>` relevant to my project that you can ignore.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>work.basil.ticktock</groupId>
    <artifactId>ticktock</artifactId>
    <name>ticktock</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>13</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>13</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>

        <vaadin.version>14.1.0.beta3</vaadin.version>

        <drivers.downloader.phase>pre-integration-test</drivers.downloader.phase>
    </properties>

    <repositories>

        <!--https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53028557/change-maven-driven-project-based-on-vaadin-11-to-vaadin-12-alpha-version-->
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </repository>

        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
             <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
             <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- Repository needed for prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
<!--            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>-->
            <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Added to provide logging output as Vaadin uses -->
        <!-- the unbound SLF4J no-operation (NOP) logger implementation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>4.0.3</version>-->
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Basil-->

<!--        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.findbugs/jsr305 &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>3.0.2</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>17.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.flywaydb/flyway-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>jetty:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Jetty plugin for easy testing without a server -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>10.0.0-alpha0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- If using IntelliJ IDEA with autocompilation, this
                    might cause lots of unnecessary compilations in the
                    background.-->
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <!-- Use war output directory to get the webpack files -->
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <allowDuplicateFragmentNames>true</allowDuplicateFragmentNames>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!--Basil-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Use the latest released version:
                https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/ -->
                <version>1.8.0</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- optional: you don't really need execution ids, but it looks nice in your build log. -->
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- optional: default phase is "generate-resources" -->
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>v10.16.3</nodeVersion>

                    <!-- optional: with node version greater than 4.0.0 will use npm provided by node distribution -->
                    <!--                    <npmVersion>2.15.9</npmVersion>-->

                    <!-- optional: where to download node and npm from. Defaults to https://nodejs.org/dist/ -->
                    <!--                    <downloadRoot>http://myproxy.example.org/nodejs/</downloadRoot>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <properties>
                <vaadin.productionMode>true</vaadin.productionMode>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>flow-server-production-mode</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>integration-tests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>9.4.15.v20190215</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <scanIntervalSeconds>0</scanIntervalSeconds>
                            <stopPort>8081</stopPort>
                            <stopWait>5</stopWait>
                            <stopKey>${project.artifactId}</stopKey>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-jetty</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>deploy-war</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-jetty</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.22.2</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <!-- Pass location of downloaded webdrivers to the tests -->
                                <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.17</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>true
                            </onlyGetDriversForHostOperatingSystem>
                            <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver
                            </rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                            <downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers/driver_zips
                            </downloadedZipFileDirectory>
                            <customRepositoryMap>
                                ${project.basedir}/drivers.xml
                            </customRepositoryMap>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <!-- use phase "none" to skip download step -->
                                <phase>${drivers.downloader.phase}</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>selenium</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

I am pasting my `<repositories>` block of my POM here, where the prereleases repository is defined, next to the add-ons repository which probably is used more often.

```
<repositories>
    <!-- to test prerelease versions of Vaadin -->
    <repository>
        <id>Vaadin Prereleases</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
    </repository>

    <!-- If you have at least 1 add-on, then you need this-->
    <repository>
        <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Nope, error: `Could not find artifact com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:pom:14.1.0alpha1 in Vaadin Prereleases (https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases)`. When I search the [XML file of that linked folder](https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases/archetype-catalog.xml) manually, I see only versions 7 & 8, no versions 10-14.

Comment: There should be a dot before alpha1: `14.1.0.alpha1`

Comment: @Tazavoo Thanks, that was one part of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sir, it is available in mvnrepository.com. I provide below the link.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin/14.1.0.alpha1

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
    <version>14.1.0.alpha1</version>
</dependency>
```

I provide below the links.

[Vaadin pre-releases moved to new repository](https://vaadin.com/blog/vaadin-pre-releases-moved-to-new-repository)

I also found the sample github link.
https://github.com/thinwire/VaadinArchetypeAlpha

Comment: Thanks for trying, but that does not work for me. Your links refer to Vaadin 7. I suspect things are different for Vaadin 14. If you have a POM working for version `14.1.0.alpha1` please post it for comparison.