# Create a new Vaadin Flow 16/17 project using plain Java Servlets without Spring/CDI

Tags: java, maven, servlets, vaadin, vaadin-flow

The [starter page](https://vaadin.com/start) for [Vaadin Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow) has changed. That page now offers new projects configured only for [Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot). The previous version of this page offered an option for "Plain Java Servlet" as well as Spring/[CDI](http://cdi-spec.org).

The Vaadin documentation suggests using a Maven archetype manually. But the Maven repositories for `com.vaadin…` appear to be aimed at Vaadin 8 and earlier, with none for Vaadin 10 and later.

The [Vaadin page on learning Maven](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/learning-maven-concepts#_what_is_an_archetype) shows an example using `viritin-vaadin-flow-archetype` as an archetype. But [Viritin](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/viritin) is a third-party project, and would add libraries I do not presently need.

➥ Is there an avenue to start a new Vaadin 16 project using only plain Java Servlets to be run on Jetty or Tomcat without Spring/CDI? (or Vaadin 17 pre-release)

Or has the Vaadin Ltd company decided to support only Spring now? (That would be most unfortunate.)

Comment: On a related note: [*Configure Maven pom to access Vaadin 14 alpha/beta pre-release*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57910701/642706)

Comment: For same question but on Vaadin 18/19, see [*Vaadin Flow 18/19 without Spring Boot?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66129888/642706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least the Maven archetype [`vaadin-archetype-application`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-archetype-application) seems to be working for versions up to v16:

```sh
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=com.vaadin -DarchetypeArtifactId=vaadin-archetype-application -DarchetypeVersion=LATEST
```

I should update that tutorial... thanks for the hint on this.

Comment: Btw, the Plain Servlet starter is still maintained here in case it helps: https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow/tree/v14

Comment: Can you explain the differences between the two avenues you linked here in your Answer and in your Comment? And can I point out this is a mess now, making it difficult for someone to start a new Vaadin project without Spring/CDI. Or is that a new company policy, to phase out support for plain Java Servlet and now require Spring? (I certainly hope not.)

Comment: Unfortunately, that archetype does not work for Vaadin Flow version 18.0.5. Using Jetty 9 or 10, I get error: Failed startup of context o.e.j.m.p.MavenWebAppContext@a7c489a{/ … and the web browser reports an HTTP 503 error.

Comment: The archetype is not maintained anymore. Too bad, because I was a big fan of it and I know of many others that like having an official archetype. Maybe this is something we can create and maintain with the help of the community? Would you be interested in helping out with this, @BasilBourque? If so, we can create an open-source project to manage this. Let me know.

There's a Servlet-only "starter app" at https://vaadin.com/start. It doesn't seem to be updated to the latest versions of Vaadin though. AFAIK, Vaadin has no plans to adopt a policy to require Spring Boot.

Comment: (A) The /start page has plain Servlet downloads for Vaadin 8 & 14, but not for Vaadin 18/19. (B) If no plain-Servlet archetype or project template for 18/19 is provided, then in effect the company *does* have a policy of requiring Spring Boot. (C) I posted a [fresh Question for Vaadin 18/19](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66129888/642706). Marcus posted an Answer there, pointing to [*Skeleton Starter for Vaadin*](https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow/tree/v18). Downloading that project does indeed work, preconfigured currently for Vaadin 18.0.5, and works for 19.0.0alpha5 as well.

Comment: The company does not have any policy to make Spring Boot required. Simply put, there's no starter for the latest short term support version with plain Servlet but there is one for the latest Long Support Version. It is possible to use Vaadin without Spring Boot and there are not current plans to change that.

Answer (score 0):

## *Hello World Starters* page

See the [*Hello World Starters*](https://vaadin.com/hello-world-starters) page on the Vaadin.com site. There you will find several starter projects. Some involve Spring, and some do not.

Those without Spring include:

- Vaadin – Plain Java (just Servlet, no Spring, no CDI, built by Maven)
- Vaadin – CDI
- Vaadin – Quarkus
- Vaadin – Gradle

You will find those across multiple versions of Vaadin.

Some versions of Vaadin also support:

- Vaadin – OSGi
- Vaadin – Karaf

[image: screenshot of Hello World Starters offering the downloads mentioned above]