# Vaadin Flow 18/19 without Spring Boot?

Tags: maven, vaadin, maven-archetype, vaadin-flow

The https://start.vaadin.com page creates a new Vaadin Flow project for versions 18 or 19 (pre-release). But the resulting project requires Spring Boot.

I do not want Spring. I do not want Spring Boot. Both solve problems I do not have. Both add complications I do not want.

Is there a way to work with Vaadin 18 or 19 *without* Spring, with just plain Servlet technology?

Is there any Maven archetype available for Vaadin 18 or 19 but free of Spring & Spring Boot? Formerly, we had the Maven archetype [*vaadin-archetype-application*](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-archetype-application). But that archetype works only for up to Vaadin 16. Fails for Vaadin 17 & 18.

As a workaround, is there some way to take Spring Boot based project generated on https://start.vaadin.com and then rip out all the Spring related parts? Or is that not viable?

Basically, this Question the same as this Question, [*Create a new Vaadin Flow 16/17 project using plain Java Servlets without Spring/CDI*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63496047/642706) but for Vaadin 18/19 rather than 16/17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [*Skeleton Starter for Vaadin*](https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow/tree/v18) as a base, using the v18 branch in this case.

[image: screenshot of the initial web app provided by Skeleton Starter for Vaadin]

Comment: Yes! That works, thank you. Downloaded a zip from that GitHub page. Comes preconfigured for Vaadin Flow 18.0.5. Also comes pre-configured with the Vaadin pre-releases repository address. So I could easily change the version to Vaadin Flow `19.0.0.alpha5`.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use [*Hello World Starters*](https://vaadin.com/hello-world-starters) page shown below.

## *Hello World Starters*

For starting a new project in the currently-supported versions of Vaadin Flow, use either:

- non-Spring alternatives at the [*Hello World Starters*](https://vaadin.com/hello-world-starters) page.
- Spring-based interactive [project-builder web app](https://start.vaadin.com/app).

The non-Spring alternative starter projects come in "Plain Servlet" flavors for [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) as well as for [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle) as your build-management tool. And another starter is configured for [Jakarta Contexts and Dependency Injection (CDI)](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/cdi/). Yet another supports [Quarkus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quarkus).

[image: screen shot of "Hello World Starters" page on Vaadin.com, listing downloads for alternative starter projects without Spring Boot]